# NSUrlSessionDownloadTask - didCompleteWithError when go in background

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

When I force my device to go in sleep mode by pressing the power button, my background task stops by calling the delegate method `didCompleteWithError` with the error :

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted

How can I configure my NSURLSession to continue the download even in sleep mode?

Is it even possible? If not, what options do I have? I need to download a file of 300Mb, so with a low connection the application will go in sleep mode before the end of the download.

Here is the creation of my session :

```
static NSURLSession *backgroundSession;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
   backgroundSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:
                       [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:
                       @"com.myapp.mytask"] delegate:self.
                       myDelegate delegateQueue:self.myQueue];
});

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [backgroundSession downloadTaskWithRequest:
                                  self.urlRequest];
[task resume];
```

Comment: The download doesn't stop directly when I lock the device. the error arrives after 5-10 seconds.

Comment: I have managed to fix this issue in our projects by using the technique here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32821437/1905256.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the *Data Protection Capability* is activated. With that enabled all files are stored with `NSFileProtectionComplete` by default, even the temporary file used to download by the `NSURLSession`:

> The default level of protection is complete protection, in which files
>   are encrypted and inaccessible when the device is locked. You can
>   programmatically set the level of protection for files created by your
>   app, as described in “Protecting Data Using On-Disk Encryption” in iOS
>   App Programming Guide.

With `NSFileProtectionComplete` activated on that file you cannot access it when the device is locked.

I'm not sure if the temporary download file can be configured to not use data protection, it seems like that is not exposed by `NSURLSession`.

Source: [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html)

Comment: NSURLSession background downloads work by handing the download off to nsnetworkd, a background daemon that continues download work on your behalf. If you're using them correctly, you don't need your app to run in the background. They'll continue even if your app is suspended.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I haven't used NSURLSession extensively yet. Any other clue what could be going wrong?

Comment: I made new test, and it appears I have this problem only when I deploy my app in-house, through my MDM. If I run the application directly from xCode on my device:it works. But when I install the application from my MDM and run it, every time the app go in background for more than 10 seconds : It stops.

Comment: At this point I'm really just guessing. Maybe your MDM policy requires all/most files to be encrypted upon screen locking (using NSFileProtection) and therefore the download daemon can no longer write to the encrypted file when the screen is locked? Once again, just guessing.

Comment: Is it possible the problem comes because Data Protection is activated? I just made an example with a new provisioning profile without data protection, and it seems to work this time.

Comment: Definitely, that seems cause the problem. See updated answer.

Comment: Been trying to solve this for days, thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: My app stops downloading after 10 seconds of device lock. This problem occurs only on some devices even if I use same code/build/prov profile to debug. Any clue? I do NSLog over `UIApplication.sharedApplication.backgroundTimeRemaining` in didWriteData:totalBytesWritten of NSURLSessionDownloadTask delegate handler.